# Wifi cuts out, requires disable/re-enable of wireless adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a Dell XPS 13 running Windows 10. Recently I've encountered an issue with the wifi connection that seems to trigger after waking from sleep, or in a weak wireless environment, or just during usage.

I lose connection to whatever wireless connection I'm on, and my computer lists no wireless networks in range. I can fix it by disabling and re-enabling the wireless adapter in Device Manager.

The adapter shows as a Dell Wireless 1560 802.11ac. I've seen this issue on every wireless connection I've tried recently (5 or so). A reboot resolves it briefly, but only as long as killing wireless in device manager.

How can I return stability to my wireless connection?

Comment: Have you checked if there's a later driver available?  I had same symptoms (not same wireless adapter tho) and updating the driver was the answer.

Comment: I manually downloaded the latest version. No change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by rolling back my wireless driver. 7.35.295.0 is the flawed version that cuts out in low signal situations, and 7.35.267.0 is the older version that works much more reliably. It's available from the Dell driver download page for the XPS 13 under "alternate versions".

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue myself mainly within weak wireless environments when I was travelling Asia.

Broadcom have issued a new version 7.35.317.0 which should fix your problems and allow you to update from 7.35.267.0. I updated the driver through device manager.

Comment: Nope, seems 7.35.317.0 still has issues - PC literally just crashed. Stick to 7.35.267.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your [device manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/where-is-device-manager) for any hardware conflicts and also updates. They will have a yellow exclamation point if your attention is needed. If you have any are correct them  and power cycle your pc, lastly retest. If this continues delete your connection and recreate it.

Comment: I have an "unknown device" but I have no idea what it is. Any way to tell? A serial number to look up or something?

Comment: Try updating it. See if that helps if all looks in order but that remove it. The PC will attempt to recreate the COM port if it seen as new.

Comment: Updating it has no effect; windows can't find drivers for it.

Comment: Alright let's delete it and test. You have a backup?